# Putting odd size int enums into very small struct?

Tags: c++, optimization, struct, enums

I have a struct that represents common playing cards using few bits.

```cpp
struct Card {
    unsigned short suit : 2;
    unsigned short rank : 4;
};
```

I'd like to use this sort of enumerator to set the rank and suit of the cards when I initialize them.

```cpp
enum class Rank {two=2, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace};
enum class Suit {hearts, diamonds, clubs, spades};
```

However, AFAIK, the size of values in enumerators is always minimum 1 byte and always a power of two. That would increase the size of every card by a lot. I tried doing `enum class Rank:unsigned short:4`, but as expected, that threw all sorts of errors.

I feel like this should be possible to achieve, but there is probably something fundamental I'm missing? Is using an `enum` just not the right solution here?

**Edit:** I asked this because I got a type-error which I assumed was due to mismatched bit-sizes between the `int`s used by `enum`, and `Card`. However, as eerorika pointed out, this is simply due to the enum being scoped, and therefore not implicitly casting.

Comment: Looks like you have six bits worth of data. Four and two bits. A single `char` will be more than enough for you, and it's trivial bitwise math to implement setting and getting either the rank or the suit.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Right, so you're thinking I should just write a functions that deal with this stuff? And do you mean that I ought to actually store this as a `char`? Isn't that bad for type-safety? I was hoping I could state `Card test_card{Suit::diamonds, Rank::ace}`.

Comment: What you should or should not do is a decision you should make yourself by evaluating the alternative approaches, and determining which one will be the best fit for your needs. All I'm doing is pointing out some alternatives.

Comment: Express train to non-portable code. Just use bitmasks or a look-up table, or like 99.9% of card games out there, notation like `AS` or `TC`. Two bytes per card, no confusion.

Comment: FWIW, having `struct card { Rank rank; Suit suit; };` is only going to cost you 52 * 4 *2 = 416 bytes.  On any "modern" (built last 10-15 years), you could have thousands of decks of cards before you noticed,  .5GB of ram ~1.3M decks.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I agree. However, this is an exercise because I'm likely to write for some not-so-modern systems in the future.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I see. I'm fairly new to C++, so I'm sort of asking what would be "best practice" for something like this. I don't think I'm experienced enough yet to make a proper judgement of what I ought to do here.

Comment: Define "not so modern". What memory constraints are you dealing with? If it's so strapped for memory that you can't use two bytes for a card then you won't have much luck with C++, you'll need to write hand-tuned assembly.

Comment: Carry on then.  Good learning exercise to use.

Comment: The problem with asking what's "best practice" is that if you ask ten C++ developers what is "best practice for <X>" you will get eleven different answers. There is no single authority that issues decrees what is or isn't best practice. An intelligent decision is made by considering all possible alternatives, fully understanding the semantics and the details of each approach, deciding which factors are more important (memory usage, maintainability, how foolproof it is, etc...); then based on how each approach stacks up against the others, based on those factors, making an intelligent choice.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Exactly, I don't know half of the factors needed to make an intelligent decision, so I'd like to hear as many of those C++ developers' answers as possible, in hopes that I'll discover something clever.

I have resolved this now, though. I have now learned it was simply a casting issue all along, and that my solution actually works. That is, given that I give up on type-safety and implicitly cast from a non-scoped enum.

Comment: @tadman Not-so-modern = very early game systems. I have been mostly writing assembly until this point. C++ not being applicable is the conclusion I've been beginning to reach, as well. Wanting to do this is something that followed over from assembly.

Comment: Yeah, on anything with <64KB of free stack memory C++ isn't really an option. You're stuck with, at best, C, and typically just banging out assembly as even the C Standard Library can be too heavy. Things like the Atari 2600 have fewer bytes than could hold this comment, so you've got to be very clever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the size of values in enumerators is always minimum 1 byte and always a power of two. That would increase the size of every card by a lot.

Actually, that wouldn't necessarily increase the size of the card at all. The size of your `Card` is two bytes, and two enumerations of one byte are also two bytes. Of course, it would be trivial to make the bit fields version use unsigned char to halve its size which isn't achievable using two enums to store the values. And, you'd still have a few unused bits to store something else.

> Is using an enum just not the right solution here?

Enums are not the right solution for packing multiple values to bitfieds.

You can still use them as values to initialise the bitfields, but you cannot use them as the type of the bitfield.

On the other hand, "right solution" depends on what one is trying to achieve. For example, trying to achieve smallest possible `Card` class doesn't necessarily result in the fastest program.

---

To have multiple cards - each using less than a byte - using bitfields, you could do something like this:

```
struct hand {
    std::uint32_t card_0_suit : 2; // 2
    std::uint32_t card_0_rank : 4; // 6
    std::uint32_t card_1_suit : 2; // 8
    std::uint32_t card_1_rank : 4; // 12
    std::uint32_t card_2_suit : 2; // 14
    std::uint32_t card_2_rank : 4; // 18
    std::uint32_t card_3_suit : 2; // 20
    std::uint32_t card_3_rank : 4; // 24
    std::uint32_t card_4_suit : 2; // 26
    std::uint32_t card_4_rank : 4; // 30

    std::uint32_t             : 2; // (unused)
};
```

That's 6.4 bits per card.

Comment: Wait, the size of `Card` is two bytes? I though it was 6 bits.

Comment: @SanJacobs It contains one `unsigned short` whose 6 bits are used for the bitfields. Rest of the bits are unused.

Comment: You can't have a 6 bit object. Minimum size is the smallest allocation unit, or 1 byte.

Comment: @eerorika Ok, right. You say I can use them as values to initialize the bitfields, but currently I'm getting `error: cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'unsigned short' with an rvalue of type 'Rank'` when I try to do that.

Comment: @SanJacobs That's because you're using a scoped enum. Either use a non-scoped enum which implicitly converts to integers, or convert the scoped enum explicitly with static_cast.

Comment: @tadman That's what I thought, so wouldn't it be one byte, not two?

Comment: Technically? It's related to the definition of "byte" or "word" on your computer, which has been 8-bit bytes going back for decades now. Before that, people [got very creative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)#Word_size_choice), with 18-bit, 36-bit and others being popular. It's termed "unit of address resolution" in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)#Table_of_word_sizes) where that used to be equivalent to word or half-word, but has now coalesced around the 8-bit byte convention. This got settled in the early 1970s.

Comment: @eerorika Of course! It was just a casting issue all along. I didn't know there was a difference in casting between scoped and non-scoped `enum`s. I thought the only difference was the use of the scope resolution operator.